# Тризна в других значениях

Tags: лингвистика

Скажите, могло ли употребляться слово "тризна" в простонародье в значении "троица"?

вот, скажем, в Сети нашел стихотворение:

......

Троица (послесловие)

Пошли метастазы? 
Проблемы с законом? 
Бросаемся сразу 
К иконам знакомым. 
А если по жизни 
Проходим нормально, 
Не молимся Тризне, 
Высокой морально. 
Ведь мы – плод греха, 
Нам "слабо" перестроиться. 
Гуляй, отдыхай, 
С светлым праздником «Троица».

.................

То, что "тризна" это поминки я в курсе,но ведь у слов встречается нередко несколько значений

Comment: Гм... честно говоря, впервые слышу, чтобы оно употреблялось в таком значении. Интересно, что скажет ученое сообщество нашего форума.

Answer (score 3):

У этого слова действительно несколько значений:

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8% D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0

У И. И. Срезневского под тризной подразумевается «борьба, состязание; страдальство, подвиг; награда; поминки». В приведённом стихотворении, скорее всего, в строчках "Не молимся Тризне, Высокой морально" имелся в виду высокий подвиг Христа, а не Троица.

В современном русском языке слово тризна в основном используется как часть фразеологизма" совершить тризну" и понимается как пиршество в честь усопшего, поминки. К празднику Троицы это относится напрямую, т.к. он совмещает в себе христианские и языческие традиции. На Троицу мы ходим в лес и пируем -это от язычества. А должны бы молиться. Но для большей части населения Троица - народные гуляния, это нам нравится, про христианскую сущность Троицы мы не вспоминаем. Троицкая суббота (вселенская, родительская, духовская, клечальная, троицкая субботка, "троицкие родители") - один из четырех общерусских календарных дней поминовения умерших; входит в праздничный цикл Семик-Троица. Посещение могил родственников нередко заканчивается веселым гулянием, которое устраивают здесь же на кладбище. Это тоже языческое,грех, но 
"Ведь мы – плод греха, Нам "слабо" перестроиться". Мы и на Пасху норовим устроить пиршество на могилах, а ведь усопшим нужна молитва, а не тризна(пиршество, гуляние). По-моему, речь об этом, напоминание о сущности слов Тризна и Троица.

Comment: Мы ведь часто обращаемся к Богу, когда нам нужна его помощь, тогда и молимся искренне, а если у нас всё хорошо, можно и не молиться, и не соблюдать христианских традиций, можно вспомнить язычество, разрешающее пьянки и всякие непотребства. Это сплошь и рядом.

Comment: Я не думаю, что автор обсуждаемых строк мог подняться до таких полетов мысли, стих сам по себе - пустой и никчемный.

Но если безотносительно к стихотворению и личности автора, то я совсем не согласен с подобной трактовкой христианской Троицы как в чем-то связанной с тризной. Праздник напрямую не связан с подвигом Спасителя, он несколько меня смысл с течением времени, но это всегда был праздник Единобожия, торжества Православия над язычеством. Троица, кстати, венчает первую "треть" церковного года посвещенную всем чадам Божиим и знаменует наступление второй, посвященной уверовавшим.

Comment: >У этого слова действительно несколько значений:   
  
Я вам ссылочку поправлю?
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0
  
Да, там есть упоминания о других значениях, но одно из них - название рок-группы, другое - польский дворянский род.   
О подвиге Христа или Троице нет ничего.  
Fuchoin Kazuki и behemothus правы.

Comment: Значит, невнимательно читали. В этимологии есть строки:«тризна» изначально обозначала жертвоприношение трёхгодовалого животного. В. Н. Топоров  выдвинул идею, что тризна обозначала три вида состязания, наподобие троеборья, или жертвоприношение трёх видов животных, символизирующих три мира — подземный, земной и небесный. Р. М. Цейтлин предложила,что в старославянском «тризна» имеется формант «изна» и значение «тройное вознаграждение».Для автора же стихотворения Высокая Тризна - память о религиозном значении слова Троица.

Comment: Даже после Вашего разъяснения не понимаю, где здесь Христианская Троица или подвиг Христа.  

Автора не обсуждаю, думаю, он протсо спутал значения. Стихо не произвело никакого впечатления. Хочется, конечно, ему вопрос задать, но вряд ли ответит.

Comment: behemothus,почему ж такое неуважение к автору стихотворения? Мне оно не кажется пустым и никчёмным. Автор верно уловил,что зачастую к Богу мы обращаемся только когда нам приспичит, многие так и делают. И сколько помню свою молодость, на Троицу мы в лес пировать ездили, ни о чём религиозном не вспоминали, атеистами были, языческая тризна была ближе.Вот автор и пытается напомнить о высоком религиозном значении праздника - о памяти об умерших. И не называет он Троицу Тризной, лишь призывает молиться Высокому, бывает ведь и Высокая Тризна, без пьянок-гулянок.

Comment: Вообще-то я не хотел здесь разбор стихов устраивать...
>Мне оно не кажется пустым и никчёмным.   
  
Это Ваше личное мнение. Я же в принципе не люблю пустого морализаторства. Кроме того есть и формальные придирки по ритму и рифме.  
  
Касательно же варианта "Высокой Тризны", то посмотрев несколько стихотворений этого Пети, просто исключил возможность такого хода мысли. Он прямолинеен донельзя, даже стихи, называемые им философскими, пишет как гвозди вколачивает.   
http://www.stihi.ru/avtor/yablokov  

>Автор верно уловил...
  
Этого мало, чтобы начать писать стихи.

Comment: Вот именно "придирки": у него классический амфибрахий(2,5,8,11) и ритм выдержан.И пустого морализаторства не вижу. А по Вашей ссылке стихотворение никак не прямолинейно,к философским он его отнёс, видимо,потому что здесь о течении времени, о связи времён и поколений. Насчёт содержания - я не люблю Rammstein и вообще тяжёлый рок, но это не значит,что эта музыка плоха, 15-летним она нравится, а если автор знает о Теночтитлане и  Кецалькоатле , я уже его уважаю. Хорошие стихи. А всем его поэзия и не должна нравиться, каждый понимает субъективно - в соответствии со своим развитием и характером.

Comment: > у него классический амфибрахий
  
Дольник это. И то с большой натяжкой.
До амфибрахия тут как до Луны.

Answer (score 1):

Я никогда ничего подобного не слышал. 
Тризна - обряд погребения у древних славян, впоследствии было перенесено и на христианский (православный) чин, не знаю, насколько это было официально, возможно просто народное название.

Среди версий этимологии нет связанных числом "три", скорее всего родственно "тереть", что в общеславянском означало "состязаться, соревноваться, соперничать" (одним из элементов тризны, видимо, были военные игрища).

С православной Троицей ни обычаи, ни этимология никак не связаны.
Отсюда имеем, что название Троицы тризной - явный ляп автора.
Если, конечно, он действительно имел в виду это, возможно, что прочтение и не соответствует авторскому замыслу, стих довольно путаный.

Comment: А Вы посчитайте:Пошли метастазы? Проблемы с законом?-ударные 2,5,8,11
 Бросаемся сразу к иконам знакомым.-2,5,8,11- это формула амфибрахия. И все остальные строки так.И рифма на месте:с законом- знакомым, нормально -морально, перестроиться-«Троица».Даже срединная рифма на месте:метастазы-сразу.

Comment: Людмишла, что мне считать, если я это воспринимаю "внутренним слухом"?!  

Считайте Вы.

Ведь м**ы** – пл**о**д грех**а** 
**UIIUI** 
Это амфибрахий? 

Это хореямб напополам с бредом.

А это "С светлым праздником «Троица»"? 
Это свист соловья-разбойника после похмелья.

> А по Вашей ссылке стихотворение никак не прямолинейно,  
     
Людмила, а Вы вообще по ней ходили? Если да, то о каком из пятидести с хвостиком "стихотворений" Вы говорите? Я прочел около десятка. Ничего кроме несварения мозгов не получил

Comment: Рифма же просто бедная и вырожденная. 
"Морально - нормально!!!"
Это из серии "Противотанковая мина" - "противобронетанковая мина".
  
Нет, Людмила, при всем к Вам уважении, по теории стиха я с Вами более спорить не буду. Я высказал свое мнение и по поводу смысла (коего нет), и по поводу формального соблюдения правил. 
  
Все что меня интересовало - это история с "Тризной". Если интересно, 
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4141

Я не нуждался в подобной поддержке, но некоторые сомнения насчет Тризны меня все-таки не оставляли. Почему и спросил.

Answer (score 1):

Мне попалось на глаза другое стихотворение другого поэта. Хотя слово *тризна* употребляется в нем традиционно, впечатление суперкорявости текста не проходит. *Заумь*, короче говоря. Неровный размер, невыразительные рифмы, сама идея стихов крайне слабая... Отдельные строки вообще трудно понять - о чем это поэт написал. Вот как еще оценить подобное творчество? 
Получился новый вопрос вместо ответа, прошу прощения у автора темы.

**Тризна**

Гол и наг лежит строй трупов,
Песни смертные прочли.
Полк стоит, глаза потупив,
Тень от летчиков в пыли.
И когда легла дубрава
На конце глухом села,
Мы сказали: «Небу слава!» —
И сожгли своих тела.
Люди мы иль копья рока
Все в одной и той руке?
Нет, ниц вемы; нет урока,
А окопы вдалеке.
Тех, кто мертв, собрал кто жив,
Кудри мертвых вились русо.
На леса тела сложив,
Мы свершали тризну русса.
Черный дым восходит к небу,
Черный, мощный и густой.
Мы стоим, свершая требу,
Как обряд велит простой.
У холмов, у ста озер
Много пало тех, кто жили.
На суровый, дубовый костер
Мы руссов тела положили.
И от строгих мертвых тел
Дон восходит и Иртыш.
Сизый дым, клубясь, летел.
Мы стоим, хранили тишь.
И когда веков дубрава
Озарила черный дым,
Стукнув ружьями, направо
Повернули сразу мы.

////////////////////////////////////
Изучив за несколько дней *историю вопроса* и мнения уважаемых форумчан, представлю свою версию происхождения слова **тризна**.
В самом раннем источнике (11 в.) приводится форма слова : *триздьный* (см. Срезневский, 3 том, 995 стр.). В дальнейшем звук и буква *д* в этом и других родственных словах пропали, *куда - неизвестно*.
По моему мнению, в балто-славянских языках и посейчас имеются современные аналоги древнего слова.
Trzydniowe (пол.), трохдзённы (белор.), tri dana (босн.), **trīs dienu** (латыш.), trijų dienų (лит.), тридневный (цся)... Латыши, кажется, лучше всех других сохранили первоначальное звучание, как вы думаете? Trīs dienu - триздьный, практически одно слово!
По обычаю, хоронили на третий день, программа прощания была насыщенной, **трехдневной**. Поскольку множество отдельных сторон обряда сливались в один *триздьный обряд* (или даже **закон**, как упоминается у Срезневского), то поэтому и зафиксировано в старинных источниках несколько весьма несхожих значений старославянской **тризны**. Последующие поминальные дни называются похожим образом : *девятый день (девятины), сороковой день (сороковины, сорочины)*.

Comment: Хлебников никогда не отличался прозрачностью образов, но это не делает его стихи плохими. Да, их трудно подчас читать, иногда в такт не попадает, но никто ж не говорит, что в этом образец для подражания. Ко всему прочему Серебряный Век - это время экспериментов. Включая и эксперименты с размером. Даже Гумилев в поледние годы жизни тоже их не избежал.

Answer (score 0):

Стихотворение плохое, хотя как раз ритм у него выдержан, на *плод* ударения нет, и амфибрахий прежнему чёткий. Недочёты тут в основном стилистические:
 1. Морализаторство и разговорные слова (нормально, слабо) сочетаются плохо.
 2. "с Светлым" при произнесении вслух будет непонятным или нарушит ритм.
 3. Запятая после "Тризна" толи предлагает молиться и Тризне, и некой "Высокой",  толи просто пуктационная ошибка.
 4. Как можно молиться морально я не знаю, может это связано с тем, что атеист, но как молиться аморально мне тоже неизвестно.
 5. Ну и, пресловутая "Тризна", которая на значение подвиг здесь не дотягивает. Хотя даже если данное значение принять, разговоры о подвиге уместны на пасху, но не "троицу".

Ну и возвращаясь непосредственно к вопросу:

> могло ли употребляться слово "тризна" в простонародье в значении "троица"?

Могло, но не употреблялось

Comment: >на плод ударения нет   
  
И Вы туда же?
На основании чего его там нет?
Я понимаю, если бы это было в конце стихотворения в одном размере (ч двумя ) написанного. Но когда одно четверостишье - в одном размере, другое в другом - и в первом же стихе второго идет дикий перебой...
Ну откуда читающий должен знать, что это амфибрахий?

>Могло, но не употреблялось  
  
Это-то как раз случалось. Дпугое дело, что "Тризна" у автора - с заглавной, как название христианского праздника, что исключает подобное толкование.  


С остальным - согласен.